# Динамическое обновление содержимого таблицы (DataTable php) с помощью JQuery Ajax GET с сохранением функциональных кнопок и полей таблицы

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, datatable

Вечер добрый, товарищи!

Небольшая предыстория к тому зачем мне это надо:

---

Для работы был создан сайт на который выводятся все заявки по ремонту и обслуживанию техники, дабы системные администраторы могли с удобством сортировать и распределять заявки между друг другом и рабочими площадками.

Сайт свою работу выполняет вполне сносно, но появилось желание видеть заявку сразу, как только она пришла, а не обновлять для этого страницу. Сайтодел из меня никакой, по этому я пошел искать решение этой проблемы на просторах интернета; Нашел JQuery, почитал документацию, сделал всё исходя из того что прочитал и...

---

Теоретически всё работает, но не совсем как надо. Дело в том, что у таблиц есть функциональные кнопки и поле поиска:

[image: Кнопки]

[image: Поиск]

А так же, для удобства, вся таблица бьется на страницы по 10 элементов:

[image: Страницы]

---

Теперь к сути проблемы, после того как я вывел таблицу в отдельный файл, и получил её с помощью JQuery GET, функциональные кнопки работают, но обновляются каждые 5 секунд (для теста взял 5 секунд, потом будет переделано на проверку новых строк в бд, и обновление при их наличии) вместе со всей таблицей, как итог если в элементе `Column Visibility` снять отображение ненужных столбцов, после обновления таблицы они сбросятся.

Это 1-ая проблема. 2-я проблема заключается в том, что перестаёт работать разделение таблицы на страницы, все данные просто выгружаются в одну таблицу, и внизу указывается только 1 страница, а так же некорректно отображается количество строк (элементов):

Должно быть так:

[image: должно быть]

А выглядит так:

[image: Неправильно]

---

Я знаю что на Stack**Overflow** лучше не задавать вопрос, если ты сам хотя бы не попробовал это сделать, и не можешь показать код своей попытки, по этому, вот кодовая база:

Код с основной страницы (куда мы получаем данные из таблицы):

```
<h2 class="font-weight-light text-center py-3 text-white">
    Активные заявки
</h2>
<div class="" id="devtest">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function datatable_wrapper() {
        $.get( "/request/datatable_undone.php", function( data ) {
            $( "#devtest" ).html( data );
            var table1 = $('#example2').DataTable({
                lengthChange: false,
                order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                buttons: ['excel', 'print', 'colvis'],
                pageLength: 10
            });
            table1.buttons().container().appendTo('#example2_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
        });
    }
    
    datatable_wrapper();
    setInterval(datatable_wrapper, 5000);
</script>
```

Код таблицы из которой мы получаем данные:

```
<?
function autoload($class) {
  include "../classes/_class.".$class.".php";
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');

# Класс конфига 
$config = new config;

# Функции
$func = new func;

# База данных
$db = new db($config->HostDB, $config->UserDB, $config->PassDB, $config->BaseDB);
?>


<table id="example2" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Номер заявки</th>
            <th scope="col">Площадка</th>
            <th scope="col">ФИО</th>
            <th scope="col">Кабинет</th>
            <th scope="col">Номер телефона</th>
            <th scope="col">E-Mail</th>
            <th scope="col">Описание проблемы</th>
            <th scope="col">Комментарий пользователя</th>
            <th scope="col">Статус заявки</th>
            <th scope="col">Комментарий администратора</th>
            <th scope="col">Создана</th>
            <th scope="col">Изменена</th>
            <th scope="col">Системный администратор</th>
            <th scope="col">Комментарий А.Урядова</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?
    $db->Query("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE `state` != 'Выполнена'");
    
    if($db->NumRows() > 0){
        while($data = $db->FetchArray()){
            $checkbox_id++;
    ?>
    <form method="POST">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?=$data["id"]; ?></th>
                <td><?=$data["place"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["name"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["cabinet"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["phone"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["email"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["trouble"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["comment"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["state"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["answer"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["req_date"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["upd_date"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["adm"]; ?></td>
                <td><?=$data["u_comment"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

---

Постарался как можно понятнее и содержательнее объяснить свою проблему, буду крайне признателен каждому кто поможет мне исправить данные проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать DataTables ServerSide. Объявление таблицы:

```
table = $('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: '/ajax.php',
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    lengthChange: true,
    order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'B><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>>rtp",
    buttons: ['excel', 'print', 'colvis']
});
```

Чтобы правильно работали кнопки в случае с ServerSide получением данных - кнопки должны быть объявлены в `dom` элементе.

Пример выгрузки данных опубликован в официальном мануале DataTables - [DataTables.net ServerSide Full Example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)

И по необходимости обновления данных в таблице использовать `ajax.reload`:

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

Так при получении данных будут функционировать кнопки и страница не будет перезагружаться, так как данные будут загружаться в фоновом режиме напрямую в таблицу.

Comment: Сейчас попробую